# how to write an iis config rule to stop redirect of .asmx

Tags: redirect, iis, asmx

I have this section in my web config to redirect http requests to https excluding .asmx references

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="(.*)" /> 
<conditions> 
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^.aspx" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
</conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" /> 
</rule>   
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

This redirects http requests OK but web services don't work - I get

```
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
 <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a 
 HREF="https://v3.myurl.net/WSEntrant.asmx">here</a></body>
```

with the error genereated at

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at PCS_Spe
```

cification.wsEntrant.WSEntrant.refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.aspx" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
> ```

You want to stop redirect of `.asmx`, but in your rewrite rule, your parameter is `.aspx`, so you need to change the parameter to `.asmx`.

Or you can also try the following rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="RewriteAllButasmx" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.asmx$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
```

Comment: I'm truly embarrassed by my typo - many thanks for spotting it